# Connecting to a device with no internet

Tags: android, android-wifi

On a fairly recent update to something android there is no longer a setting to enable connections to access points with no internet. Instead there is a pop up that says "This network has no internet access. Stay connected?" Does anyone know of a way to programmatically show this pop up? I know that I can programmatically connect to a specified Wi-Fi AP but this does not request the pop instead it just disconnects after it realizes there is not internet access. The only way I can get it to show is by going to the advanced settings and selecting the network. Any other way to get the pop up would be helpful. Thank you for your help.